# Excel 2013 Activeworkbook Protect/Unprotect issue

Tags: vba, excel

I an Excel spreadsheets that was created in Excel 2007.

The spreadsheats giving 'wrong password error' when used on Excel 2013 and when a standard VBA is run that includes:

```
   ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="passwordhere"
```

Any idea?? and how to prevent this?

I searched few threads on google and people are saying that this is a bug in excel 2013.

Comment: I have heard about the bug for the worksheets but not for the workbook. Can you do me a favor? I don't have excel 2007. Can you create a blank file and password protect it with `"passwordhere"` and upload it to www.wikisend.com. Once done share the link here. Let me test it in office 2013

Comment: if it is an xlsx document remove the password in the xml settings doc, open in 2013 and resave.

Comment: Here is the actual file - http://wikisend.com/download/926006/Microk.xls
passwords are written in sheet1.  I open the spreadsheet then if I press unprotect then it works. But if I open the spreadsheet and change a sheet and then press unprotect then it does not work.

Comment: @Sorceri, it's an xls document..

Comment: If I create a new spreadsheet, copy paste same code and save as .xls in excel 2013 then it works.